# Should I frame a wall before or after installing the subfloor?

Tags: framing, subfloor

I just ripped out the subfloor in my bathroom to make plumbing easier since I am changing the layout of my bathroom.  I also want to increase the size of the bathroom and eat into the walk-in closet adjacent to it by removing the existing wall and moving it over 3ft.  Since the subfloor is removed, can I frame the wall and attach it directly to the joists or do I have to add the subfloor first and then frame?

Framing the wall first will make my life easier - can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your wall is perpendicular to the joists? You can do that within limits, but the new subfloor edges need to be supported. This means you need a row of blocking on each side of the wall. That doesn't sound easier to me.

From an overall structural standpoint, you would not want a discontinuous subfloor the entire length of the house, but for just the length of a bathroom it shouldn't be an issue, as long as the edges are supported.

Comment: I think what he is getting at is this -- framing on top of the subfloor.  In addition to bcworkz comments, it's likely that if you do not go on top of the subfloor, you will have to do some nasty shimming at the top of your framing since the existing framing is probably all done with standard lengths of stick wood.